# Run tests for multiple language versions in GitHub actions in a Docker container

Tags: github-actions

I’m trying to setup GitHub actions for a Python package. I believe the most sane way to do so is what I’m used to from GitLab; run a set of commands inside of a docker image. I would like to use a matrix to test multiple Python versions.

So far I have defined the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Pytest

on:
  - push
  - pull_request

jobs:
  pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version:
          - 3.5
          - 3.6
          - 3.7
          - 3.8
    container: python:${{ python-version }}-alpine
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install
        run: |
          pip install poetry
          poetry install
      - name: PyTest
        run: poetry run pytest
```

The result can be seen here: https://github.com/remcohaszing/pywakeonlan/actions/runs/87630190

This shows the following error:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/pytest.yaml (Line: 17, Col: 16): Unrecognized named-value: 'python-version'. Located at position 1 within expression: python-version

How do I fix this workflow?

Answer (score 8):

A couple of points to try:

1) To use values from the matrix, you need to use `${{ matrix.python-version }}`. For more information, see the documentation for [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix).

2) You do not necessarily need to use containers to test multiple versions. GitHub Actions supports this out of the box using language specific "setup" actions. For example, see the official [setup-python](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) action. Here is an example of how they do it:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [ '2.x', '3.x', 'pypy2', 'pypy3' ]
    name: Python ${{ matrix.python-version }} sample
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          architecture: x64
      - run: python my_script.py
```